# MySQL Group Increment

Tags: php, mysql

I'm tuning up a script in one of my apps and I've hit a block. I have a routine that essentially lists all candidates interviews and prints the interview round for the job opening they're working on. Here's an example table in the database.

```
+---------+-------------------+------------+
|contactid|interviewtime      |assignmentid| 
+---------+-------------------+------------+
|1        |2016-01-01 10:00:00| 1          |
+---------+-------------------+------------+
|1        |2016-01-02 10:00:00| 1          |
+---------+-------------------+------------+
|1        |2016-01-03 10:00:00| 1          |
+---------+-------------------+------------+
|1        |2016-01-04 10:00:00| 2          |
+---------+-------------------+------------+
|1        |2016-01-05 10:00:00| 2          |
+---------+-------------------+------------+
|1        |2016-01-03 10:00:00| 2          |
+---------+-------------------+------------+
```

I would like to produce something like the following:

```
+---------+-------------------+------------+-----+----+
|contactid|interviewtime      |assignmentid|round|last|
+---------+-------------------+------------+-----+----+
|1        |2016-01-01 10:00:00| 1          |1    |no  |
+---------+-------------------+------------+-----+----+
|1        |2016-01-02 10:00:00| 1          |2    |no  |
+---------+-------------------+------------+-----+----+
|1        |2016-01-03 10:00:00| 1          |3    |yes |
+---------+-------------------+------------+-----+----+
|1        |2016-01-04 10:00:00| 2          |2    |no  |
+---------+-------------------+------------+-----+----+
|1        |2016-01-05 10:00:00| 2          |3    |yes |
+---------+-------------------+------------+-----+----+
|1        |2016-01-03 10:00:00| 2          |1    |no  |
+---------+-------------------+------------+-----+----+
```

I have managed to get the output working in PHP, but I'm having to do 2 additional queries to get the output, which is adding 1.5~ seconds to my execution time. I'm wondering if I can get MySQL to do the heavy lifting instead and hopefully bring this time down. I'm sure my current implementation will become a bottleneck as the table grows.

EDIT [2016-10-31]

I am using this query to add the windowing function of counting the rows, but I am having issues with the last piece of the puzzle which is to say whether this is the last (max) round.

```
SELECT a.round_number AS round, a.contactid, a.assignmentid
FROM (
   SELECT @round_number:=CASE WHEN @contactid=contactid THEN @round_number+1 ELSE 1 END AS round_number,@contactid:=contactid AS contactid, assignmentid
   FROM tbl_interviews, (SELECT @round_number:=0,@contactid:='') AS t
ORDER BY contactid DESC) AS a
WHERE a.contactid!= '0'
ORDER BY a.round_number DESC
```

After this, I added a further column to the parent SELECT:

```
(CASE WHEN MAX(a.round_number) < a.round_number THEN 'no' ELSE 'yes' END) AS last
```

However, this last condition is only returning one row rather than the entire dataset and is eluding me. I need to find the max round within this group and run the CASE function on it.

Comment: no, not really. mysql doesn't have windowing functions. this seems easy enough to do in client-side code, however. just keep a record of the "previous" row so you can compare it against the current one, and increment/reset your round counter as appropriate.

Comment: Thanks Marc, that's exactly what I'm doing at the moment, but at a 'cost'.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what two queries you are using to run now.
But what about something like this to make that last column conditional.

```
SELECT contacted, interviewtime, assignmetnid, round,
CASE WHEN round < 3 THEN last = 'no'
ELSE 'yes' END AS last
FROM Table
```

Comment: op wants the last of any set of rounds marked. you'd only be marking for a 3-round set. what about 4 rounds? 2 rounsd?

Comment: Valid point.. I was going off of his example where 3 rounds case was the last round.

Comment: What about `CASE WHEN round < MAX(round) THEN last = 'no' `.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai this might very well work, but we still have the issue of getting the round number...

Comment: @Rich what determines the last round? And what that variable is in the code?

Comment: @brunzzy The last round is the interview with the highest (or furthest) date in the future

Comment: Looks like something like this could work? http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2014/03/09/mysql-reset-row-number-for-each-group-partition-by-row-number/ I'm going to test and feedback

Comment: Good find @Rich, Let us know the results!